# QuickOSM TimeOut with even the smallest area in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, quickosm

QuickOSM worked beautifully in QGIS 2 but since I changed to QGIS 3 it never works. It always "timeout" for anything even in the smallest Canvas of a few houses. When I Query for "highway" it does Timeout. I tried with QGIS 3.2, 3.4, 3.8. Multiple servers. Always the same. What am I missing?

Comment: Works fine for me - as long as I remember to change the "In" dropdown to "Canvas Extent" to search the current map view. Can you paste the text of a query (the XML that starts `<osm-query>`) you are trying into your question? How long does it take to timeout? Are there any errors or messages in the QGIS logs? Copy and paste anything relevant back into your question.

Comment: Works for me too. See if this tutorial gives you any hint http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/downloading_osm_data.html

Comment: Please share the logs, the bottom right icon in QGIS, then QuickOSM panels. Please at least QGIS 3.4, QuickOSM provided with QGIS 3.2 is old and unmaintained. Click on "show query" and if you use a BBOX, click on generate query and then you share it with us. I'm the developer of QuickOSM.

Comment: Be sure you have the most up-to-date version of the plugin. It's a good idea to routinely check the "Upgradable" tab of the plugin manager. QGIS doesn't notify you when you try to use an old version of a plugin.